# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined for an .png file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to import .png files into my react native component by doing the following.

```
import background from '../../../assets/background';
import BannerLogo from '../../../assets/BannerLogo.png';
import SplashArt from '../../../assets/SplashArt.png';
```

I currently get the error

`assets/background.png:Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

There is no other error message (or info) in the terminal. However, this is the only place in my code where I am importing these images. When I change the order of the imports (e.g. BannerLogo first) I get the same error code but with

`assets/BannerLogo.png`

I am using expo SDK 40. The images are being used like so :

```
  <ImageBackground
          source={background}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            flexGrow: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
          }}
          imageStyle={{
            resizeMode: 'repeat',
          }}
        />
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong value to **source** prop.

Image are loaded through `require('path')` or `{uri: 'https://url'}`.

for more info see [official doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#source)

correct code would be

```
  <ImageBackground
          source={require('../../../assets/background.png')}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            flexGrow: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
          }}
          imageStyle={{
            resizeMode: 'repeat',
          }}
        />
```

Comment: Okay, but how would I go about importing the image then? The coding style is to import the image as a variable and then pass that variable to the source.

Comment: for image you only need to pass path in `require()`, No need to import at top like other components. You can assign `require('../../../assets/background.png')` to any variable then use that in source or you're asking for all images to import at one file and then assign in **source** from there as a variable?